# Left alignment title in arrange function in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, annotate

How do I adjust the title to the left? And also, in the `annotate_figure` can I create a subtitle? Instead of cutting the line `\n`, as I don't want the subtitle in bold.

[image]

I am using the `arrange` function to combine multiple graphs and `annotate_figure` to personalize it:

```
plotCNAE <- ggarrange(plotalimentacio_2021_decils, plottabac_2021_decils, plotvestit_2021_decils, plothabitatge_2021_decils, plotmobles_2021_decils, plotsalut_2021_decils,
                      plottransport_2021_decils, plotcomunicacions_2021_decils, plotoci_2021_decils, ploteducacio_2021_decils, plotrestaurants_2021_decils, plotaltres_2021_decils,
                       ncol=4, nrow=3, common.legend=TRUE, legend="right")
plotCNAE

annotate_figure(plotCNAE, 
                top=text_grob("Despesa monetària en els diferents grups CNAE, per decils de renda. Espanya (2021) \nEn euros i percentatge", size=15, face="bold", hjust=1, vjust=0.4),
                bottom=text_grob("Font: Elaboració pròpia a partir de dades de l'Enquesta de pressupostos familiars del 2021, base 2016, de l'INE.", hjust=1, x=1, face="italic", size=10))
```

Answer (score 0):

To align your title to the left you have to use `hjust=0` and set the position for `textGrob` to `x=0`.

Using some fake example data and plots:

```
library(ggpubr)
library(ggplot2)

p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(hp, mpg, color = factor(cyl))) +
  geom_point()

plotCNAE <- ggarrange(p, p, p, p,
  ncol = 4, nrow = 1, common.legend = TRUE, legend = "right"
)
plotCNAE

annotate_figure(plotCNAE,
  top = text_grob("Despesa monetària en els diferents grups CNAE, per decils de renda. Espanya (2021) \nEn euros i percentatge", 
                  size = 15, face = "bold", hjust = 0, vjust = 0.4, x = 0),
  bottom = text_grob("Font: Elaboració pròpia a partir de dades de l'Enquesta de pressupostos familiars del 2021, base 2016, de l'INE.", 
                     hjust = 1, x = 1, face = "italic", size = 10)
)
```

[image]